# jQuery reset dialog on cancel and close before form posting

Tags: jquery, validation, dialog

I have code that opens a dialog, validates, and posts a form when the validation is successful.

If the user clicks "Cancel," the dialog should reset until the next time it's called.

If the user clicks "OK," the dialog should close and the form should post, so if I hit the back button the dialog doesn't appear on the page.

Code is as follows:

```
<script>    
$(function(){//document ready
      $("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true
    });


  $("#confirmLink").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");


    $("#dialog").dialog(

    { minWidth: 500 },{
      buttons : {

         "Ok": function() {

            $('#flagform').submit();


            //window.location.href="modalReceipt.asp?documentGUID="+$("#documentGUID").val()+"&fycuserid="+$("#fycuserid").val()+"&reason=" + $("#reason").val()+"&other="+ $("#other").val()
            },
        "Cancel" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      },
      open: function() { 

    jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";

        $("#flagform").validate({
        invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var message = errors == 1
                    ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted below'
                    : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted below';
                $("div.error span").html(message);
                $("div.error").show();
            } else {
                $("div.error").hide();
            }
        },
        // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account

        messages: {
            reason: "*",
            explanation: "*"
            },
    });//validate

        },

    });




    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
    } );
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <a class="normal" id="confirmLink" href="">Test</a>
        <div id="dialog" title="Flag This Document" style="display:none">
            <form id="flagform" action="modalReceipt.asp" method="post">
      Please choose a reason for flagging this document and provide an explanation, if necessary.
  <p><p><div class="error" style="display:none;color:red">      <span></span>.<br clear="all"/>
</div>
 <table class="emptygrid">
<tr>
<td class="header">Reason:</td>
<td class="data">
    <select name="reason" id="reason" class="required">
        <option value="">-- Choose a Reason --</option>
        <option value="plagiarism">Plagiarism</option>
        <option value="submissionError">Submission Error</option>
        <option value="instructions">Student Didn't Follow Instructions</option>
        <option value="blankDocument">Blank Document</option>
        <option value="other">Other (please explain)</option>
      </select>


        </td>
        <td class="status"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class="header" style="vertical-align:top">Explanation:</td>
<td class="data"> <textarea name="explanation" rows="10" cols="35"></textarea></td><td class="status"></td>

</tr>


</table>
<input type="hidden" id="fycuserid" name="fycuserid" value="33"/>
<input type="hidden" id="documentGUID" name="documentGUID" value="26219247-EB85-4ABD-8F74-C8448BA06472"/>

</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If the user clicks "Cancel," the
>   dialog should reset until the next
>   time it's called.

edit your "Cancel" to something like this,

```
"Cancel": function() {
     $(this).dialog("close");
     $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
}
```

> If the user clicks "OK," the dialog should close and the form should post, so if I hit the back button the dialog doesn't appear on the page.

I suggest you do it on server-side. When submit is successful, do a cookie or session variables. Check that variable when page is loaded and do something for the dialog to appear or not appear in the page.

Comment: Would it be worth setting content... expires on the page so they can't go back?

Comment: What if the document has multiple forms? Can I do find('#formname').reset(); ?